# Variable does not exist error on custom field name

Tags: permissions, list, dml, set

I have an object XYZ having custom fields AssigneeId and PermissionSetID. Now I have a list insAssignmentList of the object XYZ. I try to add values to the list by below line inside a for loop and getting the subject line error. can someone please let me know where I am doing the mistake?

```
insAssignmentList.add(AssigneeId=u.ID,PermissionSetId=PermissionSetID);
```

Comment: Is `inAssignmentList` a `List<XYZ__c>`? If so, then your provided code has issues besides missing the `__c` for referencing custom fields.

Comment: I am sorry I changed it to XYZ__c. Still issue happens.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create new instances of `XYZ` and add those to the list:

```
List<XYZ> insAssignmentList == new List<XYZ>();
insAssignmentList.add(new XYZ(AssigneeId=u.ID,PermissionSetId=PermissionSetID));
```

(Custom objects and custom fields also have a `__c` suffix in their name as Derek F points out in his comment.)